# spring mvc json array values are converted to &#034

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp

I have this in my spring project

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String view(ModelMap request, @RequestParam("items") String Items){
    System.out.println(Items);
}
```

Prints the below json

```
{
"items":[
  {
    "price":30
  },
  {
    "price":"50"
  }
 ]
}
```

but when I pass the above json data to JSP file it converts to this

```
{&#034;items&#034;:[{&#034;Price&#034:&#034;30&#034;},{&#034;Price&#034;:&#034;50&#034;}]}
```

How to decode this so I can display properly in my view?
And btw the above req param I am getting is encoded url JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes get converted to this &#034 HTML ASCII because you are not using escape characters. You can use \" (escape character, to pass double quotes as it is.).
forex.

```java
String jsonData = "{ \"key\" : \"value\" }";
```

Or you can use a library such as Jackson to Parse your JSON for you.